What should I do if I don't see the dotenv method after installing dotenv in python
I accidentally deleted some files from the project (I don't remember exactly which ones) but it was possible to restore everything except load_dotenv. After pip install python has been executed, dotenv still does not see load_dotenv, although the package is installed. What should I do?


I tried reinstalling the package and also updating it to the current version, but despite all this still does not see this function. Does it make sense to create a new project and transfer everything to it?

If nothing works, why not just recreate the venv?

Did you install with
pip install python-dotenv

or with
pip install dotenv

Check with
pip freeze

You should use first one. Second one is a common mistake and is not maintained.

I'm installed with "pip installed Python-donenv", but didn't worked. As a result, I deleted the project and created a new one, into which I inserted the previous code and installed all the libraries and everything worked, and thank you for your answer!
